# Send SMS from my php file using get-url in kannel

Tags: php, url, ubuntu, sms, kannel

Here'is a kannel service:

```
group = sms-service
keyword-regex = "^regexhere[abc]"
get-url = "http://localhost/abc/sms/sendsms.php?sender=%p&name=%a"
```

I wanna verify name i.e. %a from my database from my file "sendsms.php" and then want to send SMS but unable to send sms after verifying the name with db. Here's my code:

```
$to=$_GET['sender'];
$username=$_GET['name']; 

//verifying received username       
if($getusername = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as count FROM tablename where username ='".$username."'", $DB))) {
if ($getusername['count']==0) {     
        header("Location: http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=kanneluser&password=foo&to=".$to."&text=Wrong User name, Please SMS valid user name!");
}
    else {
        header("Location: http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=kanneluser&password=foo&to=".$to."&text=text here!");
    }
}
```

Am I calling the URL in the true manner? 
Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Try to use `urlencode` for the value of the "text" parameter

Comment: Also, use something like `file_get_contents` to make the HTTP call from your server. If you use a Location redirect, the HTTP call is made from the client browser.

Answer (score 0):

To have auto replay via get-url simply use echo in your if loop no need to call the send url api of kannel.

```
if ($getusername['count']==0) {     
    echo "Wrong User name, Please SMS valid user name!";
}
else {
    "text=text here!";
}
```